# Java Spring, Whitelabel error, trouble getting my first project going

Tags: java, spring

I'm having trouble getting my first Java Spring project to run with an html template. I put the template in to src/main/resources/templates. The controller method is successfully called. But the template isn't called, instead I get the Whitelabel error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Nov 20 19:43:09 EST 2015
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? If I add @ResponseBody to the controller, it prints the string to the screen, but I can't figure out how to get the template to come through. Thanks.

MasterSpringMvcApplication.java

```
package masterSpringMvc;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MasterSpringMvcApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MasterSpringMvcApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

HelloController.java

```
package masterSpringMvc.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {


    public String hello() {
        System.out.println("HelloController called!");
        return "resultPage";
    }
}
```

resultPage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Hello thymeleaf</title>
</head>
<body>
    <span th:text="|Hello thymeleaf|">Chup Html</span>
</body>
</html>
```

build.gradle

```
....
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') 
}
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `@RequestMapping("/")` to controller method. In your case -

```
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String hello() {
        System.out.println("HelloController called!");
        return "resultPage";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks localhost999, but I already have it there. I've tried it inside the class and outside of it.

Comment: Thanks for responding. That solution worked for me. Try @RequestMapping("/hello") on the method and test with url http://localhost:8080/hello

Comment: Ok. I have limited access right now as I am travelling. Are you using maven?Also Make sure that src/main/resources/templates is in your buildpath